# .htaccess not redirecting inside public folder php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I"m trying to create a redirect from an existing project, but for some reason is not working
So I tried to do a test from zero and for some reason still not working.
My test project

[image]

I'm starting the PHP this way

[image]

And my .htacess is this way

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

And my file inside the public folder

[image]

But for some reason when I call the URL does not show the index in the public folder

[image]

Comment: What URL did you call?

Answer (score 2):

You are using php builtin web server. PHP Builtin web server doesn't support .htaccess. You should install and configure apache web server.

Comment: Thank you, I'll configure the apache web server.